# Why does container does't execute scripts inside /etc/my_init.d/ on startup?

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.16

RUN mv /build/conf/ssh-setup.sh /etc/my_init.d/ssh-setup.sh

EXPOSE 80 22

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

My `/build/conf/ssh-setup.sh` looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

echo "${SSH_PUBKEY}" >> /var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys

chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/.ssh
chmod go-rwx -R /var/www/.ssh
```

It just adds `SSH_PUBKEY` env to `/var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys` to enable ssh access.

I run my container just like the following:

```
docker run -d -p 192.168.99.100:80:80 -p 192.168.99.100:2222:22 \
   -e SSH_PUBKEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" \ 
   --name dev hub.core.test/dev
```

My container starts fine but unfortunately `/etc/my_init.d/ssh-setup.sh` script does't get executed and I'm unable to ssh my container.

Could you help me what is the reason why `/var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys` doesn't get executed on starting of my container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a pretty similar issue, also using phusion/baseimage. It turned out that my start script needed to be executable, e.g.

```
RUN chmod +x /etc/my_init.d/ssh-setup.sh
```

Note:

I noticed you're not using baseimage's init system ( maybe on purpose? ). But, from my understanding of their [manifesto](http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/), doing that forgoes their whole "a better init system" approach.

My understanding is that they want you to, in your case, move your start command of `node server.js` to a script within `my_init.d`, e.g. `/etc/my_init.d/start.sh` and in your dockerfile use their init system instead as the start command, e.g.

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.16

RUN mv /build/conf/start.sh /etc/my_init.d/start.sh
RUN mv /build/conf/ssh-setup.sh /etc/my_init.d/ssh-setup.sh

RUN chmod +x /etc/my_init.d/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /etc/my_init.d/ssh-setup.sh

EXPOSE 80 22

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
```

That'll start baseimage's init system, which will then go and look in your `/etc/my_init.d/` and execute all the scripts in there in alphabetical order. And, of course, they should all be executable.

My references for this are: [Running start scripts](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#running_startup_scripts) and [Getting Started](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#getting_started).

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer states you did not execute ssh-setup.sh.  You can only have one process in a Docker container (that is a lie, but it will do for now).  Why not run ssh-setup.sh as your CMD/ENTRYPOINT process and have ssh-setup.sh exec into your final command, i.e.

```
exec node server.js
```

Or cleaner, have a script, like boot.sh, which runs any init scripts, like ssh-setup.sh, then execs to node.

Answer (score -1):

Because you didn't invoke `/etc/my_init.d/ssh-setup.sh` when you started your container. 
you should call it in CMD or ENTRYPOINT, read more here

> RUN executes command(s) in a new layer and creates a new image. E.g.,
>   it is often used for installing software packages. 
>   CMD sets default
>   command and/or parameters, which can be overwritten from command line
>   when docker container runs. 
>   ENTRYPOINT configures a container that
>   will run as an executable.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I already have CMD already that executes node.js server. Can I invoke my ssh-setup.sh script together with him?

Comment: Try to rebuild your image with CMD
`CMD node server.js ; /etc/my_init.d/ssh-setup.sh`

Comment: Do you mean `CMD ["/etc/my_init.d/ssh-setup.sh", "node", "server.js"]` ?

Comment: There are 2 form of CMD : shell form and exec form. My CMD is shell form and I'm not sure how to migrate from shell form it into exec form, you can try my CMD to rebuild your image.